nvim lsp and lsp-config restarting server on new nvim instance
So I have the LSP client and lsp-config setup and running for typescript and golang.
The problem is when every I start up nvim a project, it takes about 1~2 minutes before the LSP is ready and I can actually use the hover, definition jumping and so on.
https://github.com/neovim/nvim-lspconfig/blob/master/doc/lspconfig.txt
From what I have read in the docs linked above, it seems if the root_dir is provided and matched, then the LSP server should only be spun up once for that root_dir?
ROOT DETECTION                                        *lspconfig-root-detection*
                                                            *lspconfig-root-dir*

A project's `root_dir` is used by `lspconfig` to determine whether `lspconfig`
should start a new server, or attach a previous one, to the current file.

Example
I go into my golang project, nvim <filename> to open a go file in nvim.
In Activity Monitor I can see a gopls process is started. It takes some time, but the LSP is eventually ready.
Now if I exit nvim, the gopls process is gone, and when I reopen nvim, I have to again wait a couple minutes before everything is ready.
This is my config for gopls lsp server setup via lspconfig
local lspconfig = require('lspconfig')
lspconfig.gopls.setup {
    cmd = {"gopls"},
    filetypes = {"go", "gomod", "gowork", "gotmpl"},
    root_dir = util.root_pattern("go.work", "go.mod", ".git"),
    single_file_support = true,
}

Is there some config that I am missing? I have tried turning single_file_support to false, but still same behavior.

In your configuration, you are using the default values for gopls LSP server with lspconfig plugin, according to https://github.com/neovim/nvim-lspconfig/blob/master/doc/server_configurations.md#gopls I'm using the same configuration as yours, without issue (diagnostics, hover, go to definitions/references via gopls). When you open your Go file with Neovim, are you in the root directory of your project ?

I have tried both opening from root and child directories. :LspInfo shows that it is detecting the correct root_dir.
It seems that the indexing that happens per session of nvim is expected. I might try either setting the lsp to exclude certain directories from indexing or using git-sparse-check.
The code base is quite a large monorepo.

If your project is a large monorepo with a lot of files and directories, it's normal that gopls takes (a lot of) time when indexing it. And there is no cache between each gopls "session" (exec a new gopls process via lspconfig each time you open Neovim).
